# r coding issue with frequency and date recognition

Tags: r

I'm having a few issues with my r scripting. I have 2 issues:

- I'm able to read my data as a read.csv file, but it does not recognize the dates, it recognizes them as numeric.
- When I ask for the frequency it says that the frequency is one when it is 365.

  D.H.ASTRA <- ts(read.csv("highastra.csv"),start=c(1993,5, frequency=365))

Comment: Welcome to SO. To help us answer the question, you need to make your data available so that other people can reproduce it.  What is in `highastra.csv`?

Comment: highastra.csv is the name of the data. thx

Comment: I get that `highastra.csv` is your data file, but no-one on SO has access to it.  You either need to make it available in the question (use `dput`) somewhere else online, or provide a dummy dataset that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> the frequency is one when it is 365

Take a look at the parentheses in the code `start=c(1993,5, frequency=365)`.  `frequency` should be outside the parentheses, since it is an argument all by itself, not part of `start`.

Comment: first of all thanks guys. i gave it a go but still getting an error or the same frequency.

Comment: If you still have problems, update your question to show what you tried.  We can't help you unless you describe what you have done and exactly what went wrong.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example